# Передача кириллицы на сервер

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

При передачи сообщения, содержащим кириллицу, сервер отображает:

> [B@163fa4e.

Сообщение передаю в UTF-8. Но серверу не удается прочесть его корректно.

*Как справится с этой проблемой?*

Метод кодирования:

```
    try {
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new       SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), SHA_TYPE);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(SHA_TYPE);
        mac.init(signingKey);
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(VALUE.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        byte[] hexArray = {
                (byte)'0', (byte)'1', (byte)'2', (byte)'3',
                (byte)'4', (byte)'5', (byte)'6', (byte)'7',
                (byte)'8', (byte)'9', (byte)'a', (byte)'b',
                (byte)'c', (byte)'d', (byte)'e', (byte)'f'
        };
        byte[] hexChars = new byte[rawHmac.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < rawHmac.length; j++ ) {
            int v = rawHmac[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }


  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost (url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        String holder = CreateCard.fullName.getText ().toString();

        byte bytes[] = holder.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String s =  new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject ();
        jsonObject.accumulate ("cardHolder", s);
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity (json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity (se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
        String hash;
        String key =  ModelAuth.salt + Autorization.smsCode;
        hash = hmacSha (key, json, "HmacSHA256");
        httpPost.setHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader ("language", "RU");
        httpPost.setHeader ("sessionId", ModelAuth.sessionId);
        httpPost.setHeader ("reqSign", hash);
        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute (httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity ().getContent ();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if (inputStream != null){
            result = convertInputStreamToString (inputStream);
        }
        else
            result = "Did not work!";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d ("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage ());
    }
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: Покажите как и что передаёте. Кажется, вам надо `toString()` переопределить

Comment: Я передаю в post запросе имя и фамилию пользователя. Передается все закодированное в HmacSHA256. Какая часть вас интересует? Я бы мог продемонстрировать вам хоть весь класс, только давайте обговорим как это сделать вам удобнее.

Comment: Просто я не первый день сражаюсь с этой проблемой и никак не могу найти ее решение.

Comment: @ИгорьТовкач приведите [минимальный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Обычно это порядка 20-50 полностью самодостаточных строк, которые демонстрируют проблему. В вашем случае, видимо, потребуется и код клиента, и код сервера. Возможно, кто-то угадает проблему и без кода, но ценность такого вопроса невелика - слишком неоднозначно происходящее.

Comment: Вообще говоря, `[B@163fa4e` очень похоже на результат вызова метода `toString()` у `byte[]`. Я предполагаю, что вы либо в сервере пытаетесь вывести на экран массив байт при помощи обычного `print` или `toString()`, либо в клиенте пытаетесь передать массив байт методу, который принимает `String`, и сами написали `toString()`.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что я что то с кодировкой накрутил.

Comment: Я добавил код где кодируется в HmacSHA256

Comment: Покажите как происходит отправка на сервер.

Comment: Добавил метод отправки

Comment: С методом отправки совсем очевидных проблем не видно. Полагаю, что проблема в том месте, где вы выводите полученные данные на экран.

Comment: я просто подозреваю, что в момент получения хеша, может быть какая то проблема. Бекенд делал не я, и я не имею доступа к нему. А человек говорит, что там все в порядке